# How do I attach (not link) an image to a signature in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I am not asking how to link an image to my signature, that is very straightforward. What I am wondering, is how to attach an embedded image to all emails, so that I can use it in my signature without requiring the recipient to make an external request for it.

[base64 encoded images in email signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures/9110164#9110164) describes how the resulting multipart emails should be structured.